# Android : Getting response "200 ok" but Retrofit fails

Tags: android, web-services, kotlin, retrofit

I am posting JSON array with Retrofit2 but when i post it, i'm getting "200 Ok" response and retrofit's onFailed method being called. And it says "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $"

Do i successfully send the JSON to WebService? If it's successful then why Retrofit fails? 
My JSON array like this:

```
[{"Date":"2019-01-01T00:00:00","Duration":"25","Type":1,"Number":"53201","id":0,"isDataSent":false,"Name":"test isim","phoneNumber":"5554242422"}]
```

I have test the JSON with PostMan. It is fine.

My Retrofit request like this:

```
RetrofitClient.getClient()
            .postCallModel(list)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<List<CallLogModel>>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<CallLogModel>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d(tag,"Retrofit Failed!")
                    Log.d(tag,call.toString())
                    Log.d(tag,t.message)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<CallLogModel>>, response: Response<List<CallLogModel>>
                ) {
                    Log.d(tag,"Retrofit Succeeded!")
                    Log.d(tag,response.message())
                }
            })
```

Is there an expert to help me with this?

My model class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "supportCallLog")
data class CallLogModel(
@SerializedName("Name")
val userName: String,
@SerializedName("phoneNumber")
val userPhone: String,
@SerializedName("Number")
val customerPhone: String,
@SerializedName("Time")
val callDuration: String,
@SerializedName("Type")
val callType: Int,
@SerializedName("Date")
val callDate: String,
var isDataSent : Boolean
){
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id : Int = 0
 }
```

My Retrofit Interface:

```
interface RetrofitService {
@POST("api")
fun postCallModel(@Body callLogModel: List<CallLogModel>) : Call<List<CallLogModel>>
   }
```

Comment: Add the OkHttp logging interceptor to your Retrofit setup and see what the Web service is returning. It does not appear to be the JSON that you are expecting.

Comment: Please post your CallLogModel classs

Comment: @CommonsWare yes i already added the logging interceptor and Web-service returning "200 ok" which means "successful". But retrofit's onFailed method getting called.

Comment: Also post the response array from server. Actual Problem is in there

Comment: @Swayangjit i shared my Model class.

Comment: Probably response from server return JsonObject rather than JsonArray. Thats way you get 200 but when it try to parse array it fails

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Web service is returning "200 ok" i don't think there is a problem in backend.

Comment: But you expecting a array in return: `Call<List<CallLogModel>>`

Comment: But i have to expect that type otherwise "enqueue" method doesn' work. I am posting json not getting. Why would i have to take care what returns from server?

Comment: "Web-service returning "200 ok"" -- it is returning more than that. That is the first line of the response. The OkHttp logging interceptor can report to you all of the headers and the body of the response. "I am posting json not getting" -- your code is set up to receive a `List<CallLogModel>` as a response.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a way to make my postCallModel() method void? I don't want anything in return. But if i make it void, enqueue method doesn't work.

Comment: You are using the legacy `Call` approach (instead of coroutines or something like that), so you need to have a `Call` as part of the return type. Try having it return `Call<Unit>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes i made the return type like Call<Any> it works like a charm. Thanks for idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your `POST` is correct and thats why you get 200. But problem is in your response from server. It expect a `array` but getting `object`, which leads this error.

Comment: You are assuming that the REST endpoint is returning a `CallLogModel`. What evidence do you have for this?

Comment: But it says "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING" it returns string. If i make it Call<CallLogModel> then it is gonna say "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING"

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have no evidence. It is an example to avoid **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY ** exception, he can add anything what he need. Moreover he is not bother about return element.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with @CommonsWare's help. I am posting json but i have to handle the response that comes from web service. And web service returns String. So i have changed the return type of my postCallModel()

Old return type was like this:

```
Call<List<CallLogModel>>
```

And i changed it to:

```
Call<Any>
```

Now i don't have to worry about what type of response web service returns.